# How to ignore the Time in a Date Query with JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm having problems doing a query on JPQL using a Date (and ignoring the Time). This is my method:

```
@Override
public List<Event> findByDayAndStatus(User usr, Date d, char status) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Event as e where " +
                             "e.idusr=:usr AND e.datestart=:d AND " + 
                             "e.status=:status", Event.class);            
    q.setParameter("usr", usr);
    q.setParameter("datestart", d, TemporalType.DATE);
    q.setParameter("status", status);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

The problem is I'm getting an empty list and when I omit the date parameter in the query I get my data.

I think is a problem with the date since the way I'm querying is like 2013-03-20 00:00:00 and the database date is like 2013-03-20 12:00:00.

Comment: which kind of data that you want, just 2013-03-20 00:00:00? or the data in 2013-03-20?

Comment: I want the entire data (date and time) using just the date as parameter for the query

Answer (score 0):

Modify the query as
SELECT e FROM Event as e where e.idusr=:usr AND cast(e.datestart as date) =:d AND e.status=:status 
It will skip the time from your given date and only return the date.

Comment: though not sure, but I still think that the cast is not supported by the current jpa2

Comment: you may have given cast(e.dateStart as DATE), the date should be given in small letters and caps. Verify that.